# YAMAHA RT58i でローカルエリア内の名前解決をする設定方法は？

Tags: linux, bash, dns

## 実現したいこと

家庭内（ローカルエリア内）にあるIoTデバイスのIPアドレスを固定してローカルエリア内からホスト名又はFQDNでIoTデバイスに接続できるようにしたいと思っています。

- 指定したMACアドレスをもとにIoTデバイスのIPアドレスを固定したい。
- 固定したIPアドレスのデバイスに対してローカルエリア内からホスト名又はFQDNでアクセスしたい。

※外部（インターネット側）からのアクセスは想定していません。ローカルエリア内（192.168.0.xxx）内での名前解決を想定しています。

```
ローカルエリア内からアクセスする例）
ping pi
ping pi.local
```

## 現在の環境

回線 : AU光
Modem : NEC Aterm BL172HV

```
           Aterm BL172HV
Internet ----- Modem ----- HUB ----- TV
            192.168.0.1           |- iPhone
              DHCP on                 ：
```

## 変更後の環境

DHCP,DNS 専用 Server : YAMAHA RT58i  
※ルーターですが機能を提供する意味でServerと記しています。

```
                                   HOST-NAME
            Aterm BL172HV           DHCP on
Internet ----- Modem ----- HUB ----- RT58i     192.168.0.2     固定
            192.168.0.1           |- TV        192.168.0.??    自動
              DHCP off            |- iPhone    192.168.0.??    自動
                                        ：
                                  |- lg-gram   192.168.0.99    RT58i側で固定
                                  |- rmmini3   192.168.0.100   RT58i側で固定
                                  |- wittyir   192.168.0.101   RT58i側で固定
                                        ：
                                  |- pi        192.168.0.220   RT58i側で固定
```

- YAMAHA RT58i は DHCP,DNS Server 機能を使用する。 ※ルーター機能は使わない
  Modem の Aterm BL172HV はゲートウェイとして機能させる。

## やった事

- ルーター設定に詳しくありませんのでいろんなサイトを調べて設定した内容が以下の通りです。（長いので末尾に記載いたします）
- RT58i側でIoTデバイスのIPアドレスを固定できませんでした。
- FQDNでpingが通りませんでした。（ping pi , ping pi.local）

## 疑問

そもそも RT58i で実現できるのでしょうか？

## RT58i 設定

```
#   RT58i Rev.9.01.50 (Mon Apr 25 22:01:36 2011)
#       MAC Address : 00:a0:de:4f:e5:d8, 00:a0:de:4f:e5:d9
#       Memory 32Mbytes, 2LAN, 1BRI
#       main:  RT58i ver=c0 serial=N1M168109 MAC-Address=00:a0:de:4f:e5:d8 MAC-Address=00:a0:de:4f:e5:d9
#
#   Reporting Date: Jan 1 19:05:21 1980

# If you want to clear ALL configuration to default,
#  remove `#' of next line.

#clear configuration

#
# System configuration
#

administrator password pass
login user admin encrypted OChbuEjp.U4cNwtsd99Pdudp0R/0TdK.WsCHJ

#
# IP configuration
#

ip route default gateway 192.168.0.1

#
# IPv6 configuration
#


#
# LAN configuration
#

ip lan1 address 192.168.0.2/24
ip lan1 secure filter in 100000 100001 100002 100003 100004 100005 100006 100007 100099

#
# ISDN configuration
#


### BRI 1 ###


#
# Provider Type configuration
#

provider lan1 name LAN:

#
# PP configuration
#

pp disable all

#
# TUNNEL configuration
#

tunnel disable all

#
# LOOPBACK/NULL configuration
#


#
# IP filter configuration
#

ip filter 100000 reject * * udp,tcp 135 *
ip filter 100001 reject * * udp,tcp * 135
ip filter 100002 reject * * udp,tcp netbios_ns-netbios_dgm *
ip filter 100003 reject * * udp,tcp * netbios_ns-netbios_dgm
ip filter 100004 reject * * udp,tcp netbios_ssn *
ip filter 100005 reject * * udp,tcp * netbios_ssn
ip filter 100006 reject * * udp,tcp 445 *
ip filter 100007 reject * * udp,tcp * 445
ip filter 100099 pass * * * * *

#
# IP dynamic filter configuration
#


#
# NAT Descriptor configuration
#


#
# IPv6 filter configuration
#


#
# IPv6 dynamic filter configuration
#


#
# Cooperation configuration
#


#
# Queueing configuration
#


#
# SYSLOG configuration
#


#
# TFTP configuration
#

tftp host 192.168.0.10

#
# TELNETD configuration
#


#
# DHCP configuration
#

dhcp service server
dhcp server rfc2131 compliant except remain-silent
dhcp scope 1 192.168.0.10-192.168.0.250/24
dhcp scope bind 1 192.168.0.200 b8:27:eb:00:a8:28
dhcp scope bind 1 192.168.0.100 78:0f:77:b3:98:48
dhcp scope bind 1 192.168.0.99 d4:25:8b:03:6d:bc
dhcp scope option 1 dns=192.168.0.2

#
# DHCPC configuration
#


#
# DNS configuration
#

dns service recursive
dns server 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 106.187.2.33
dns domain local
dns private address spoof on
ip host lg-gram 192.168.0.99
ip host pi 192.168.0.220
ip host rmmini3 192.168.0.100
ip host wittyir 192.168.0.101
dns private name rt58i

#
# WINS configuration
#


#
# SNMP configuration
#


#
# Schedule configuration
#


#
# X25 configuration
#


#
# TCP configuration
#


#
# HTTPD configuration
#


#
# Netvolante DNS configuration
#


#
# PSTN configuration
#


#
# ANALOG configuration
#

analog supplementary-service pseudo call-waiting
analog extension dial prefix line
analog extension dial prefix sip prefix="9#"

#
# UPnP configuration
#


#
# SIP configuration
#


#
# Mail check configuration
#


#
# Mail transfer configuration
#


#
# HTTP Revision Up configuration
#


#
# Operation configuration
#


#
# SSHD configuration
#

sshd service on
sshd session 2
sshd host key generate 3878 ubRJc......nwXLVV+Ek=

#
# USB host configuration
#


#
# NTP configuration
#


#
# SNTPD configuration
#


# If you want to save configuration to Nonvolatile memory,
#  remove `#' of next line.

#save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCPサーバ設定に`192.168.0.220`のものが抜けているからではないでしょうか?

```
    # 抜けていると思われるもの。(xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx はIoT機器のMACアドレス)
    dhcp scope bind 1 192.168.0.220 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

いかがでしょうか?

Comment: お恥ずかしい、
気付きませんでした。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score -1):

外部からIP接続可能にするためには、固定のグローバルIPアドレスを取得してください。

固定IPの取得については、[【auひかりで固定ipを使いたい！】動的ipのauひかりで固定ipを使う方法を解説！](https://xn--54qx9kpt2b.tokyo/auhikari/auhikari_koteiip.html)などのページ等を参考にしてください。

192.168.で始まるIPアドレスはプライベートIPアドレスなので、同じアドレスを持つマシンが世界中に山ほどあります。そのため、プライベートIPアドレスではマシンが特定できず、結果として通信できない事になります。

プライベートIPアドレスの詳細については、[IPアドレス(Wikipediaのページ)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9)の"プライベートIPアドレス"のところを読んでください。

RT58i は古い(2006年発売)の装置なので、現行のWiFiルータに買い替えることをお勧めします。

WiFiルータでポートフォワーディングすることにより、１つのグローバルIPアドレスで複数の装置に外部からアクセスできます。（個々にプライベートアドレスを持つ装置を、同じグローバルIPアドレスだがポート番号が異なるマシンのように見せかけることができます）

ちなみに、RT58iはブロードバンド対応のルータであって、サーバではありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。外部からの接続は想定していません。あくまでも内向き（ローカルエリア内）だけの名前解決を行いたいと思っております。誤解を生む質問となり申し訳ございませんでした。